# Why does my program keep going into my input validation loop?

Tags: c++, string, while-loop, operators

OK I'm sure its something really little that I'm missing but here is what I have:

```
 int main()   
 {
        string red = red, blue = blue, yellow = yellow, color1, 
        color2, mixResult;

        cout << "Please enter a primary color." <<endl;
        cin >> color1;

        while ((color1 != red) || (color1 != blue) || (color1 != yellow))
        { 
         cout << "Error!: Please enter a primary color." <<endl;
         cout << " *NOTE ALL ENTRIES MUST BE LOWERCASE* " <<endl;
         cin >> color1;
        }
```

Now for some reason every time I run this and enter for example red the program goes into the while loop, which it shouldn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can show more of my code and I am using #include

Comment: `string red = red, blue = blue, yellow = yellow` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Assuming you fix @DieterLücking issue, (how did you get it to compile?), the logic is wrong.  If the color is yellow, then it's not red, so 'color1 != red' is true.  No need to even look at the other expressions that are OR'd with it.

Comment: There's no color that would would turn more than one `!=` into `false`, so at least two sub-expressions of an `||` would be `true`. It takes one `true` sub-expression to turn an OR into a `true`, so your loop would never finish. Net result is that you need an `&&`.

Comment: Anyway, have a down and close vote for the string init UB issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop look wrong. it should be like this.

Fix:
`while ((color1 != red) && (color1 != blue) && (color1 != yellow))` //if the input is not equal to any of these colors.

Your's
 `while ((color1 != red) || (color1 != blue) || (color1 != yellow))`//if the input is RED, first condition is false but second and third conditions are true. that is why it is looping.

Answer (score 0):

`while ((color1 != red) || (color1 != blue) || (color1 != yellow))`

Since `color1` can only be a single value, unless `red == blue == yellow`, this loop will run forever. What you meant is probably

`while ((color1 != red) && (color1 != blue) && (color1 != yellow))`

Further, as others have pointed out, you need to properly initialize your string variables by surrounding their text with quotes:

`string red = "red", blue="blue", yellow="yellow"`

Otherwise what you're doing amounts to:

```
string red; // red is an uninitialized string
red = red;  // no kidding?! :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialized your colors to itselfs, which is undefined behaviour. Use string constants instead. And you should use &&, not ||.

Correct code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string red = "red", blue="blue", yellow="yellow", color1;

    cout << "Please enter a primary color." <<endl;
    cin >> color1;

    while ((color1 != red) && (color1 != blue) && (color1 != yellow))
    {
        cout << "Error!: Please enter a primary color." <<endl;
        cout << " *NOTE ALL ENTRIES MUST BE LOWERCASE* " <<endl;
        cin >> color1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have stated, the problem is in the condition of the while. You must use `&&` in this case.

Think of it this way, if `color1` is assigned a value of "blue", it is not "red" therefore the condition `color1 != "red"` is `TRUE`.

The same applies to the rest of the values, so the whole condition will continue to be `TRUE` even if the value of `color1` is one of the accepted values.